# css keyframe animation rotation returns to 0 degrees after completion (undoes itself)

Tags: css, css-animations, transformation, image-rotation

This is a css question specifically -thank you.  So, in a keyframe animation I am translating and rotating.  Both work, but the rotation rotates 365 degrees, and then promptly undoes itself.   I think I am missing something basic. Thank you for your support and advice.

```
    <!-- in html -->
    <div class="batgroup">
        <img id="batgirl" src="imgs/batgirl-ts.png">
    </div>

/** in css file **/ 
    #batgirl {
        position: absolute;
        left: 1080px; 
        top: 320px;
        z-index: 2; 
        animation-direction: forward; 
        animation: peoplemove 4s 0s linear forwards; 
      }

    @keyframes peoplemove{

        50% {
            transform: translate(-150px, -70px) ;   
        }

        75% {
            transform: translate(-250px, 0px) rotate( -360deg) ;
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(-350px, -70px) ;       
        }
    } /* end keyframe */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not put a rotate() at the 100% position of the animation, it assumes you would like to rotate back to zero degrees, this can simply be fixed by putting another rotate().

```
@keyframes peoplemove{

    50% {
        transform: translate(-150px, -70px) ;   
    }

    75% {
        transform: translate(-250px, 0px) rotate( -360deg) ;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-350px, -70px) rotate( -360deg) ;       
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I really appreciate it.  I did try your suggestion.  My issue is that the image rotates 360 degrees, and then immediately undoes itself at that keyframe, and continues on for the other transformations.  So, it is true if I put the additional rotate at the end it could act as a correction, but unfortunately it is not solving the problem I currently have - thanks so very much